# Is there such a things as an "Optimum height above the bed" for a Resin printer, and if so, how do you calculate it?

Tags: resin, support-structures, print-orientation

Presuming that you are raising your print above the bed using a raft and supports, rather than printing directly on the plate.

Is there such a thing as an optimum distance above the bed to have the first layer of the model being printed, and if so, is this an arbitrary distance determined by the software\support settings that you are using (For example does using Chitubox at its default settings have an optimum height), or by the dimensions of the model, or is this something that you would calculate based on things such as the printer resolution that you are using, and thus would vary between printers even with the same model>

For example - on this random image pulled off of the internet - is there a specific reason why you would want the lowest part of the model to be at that exact height, and would making it slightly higher\lower have any real impact?

[image: Example image?]

My main motivation for asking this question is that people will often angle their prints specifically so that they will require fewer vertical layers to print, and thus print faster, so it would be logical to think that they would also print their models as close to the bed as possible for the same reason, yet this doesn't seem to be the case.

Logically printing too height would increase the failure rate by having long thin supports, and would increase print times, but printing too low?